# Android Проблема с кодировкой символов из метаданных mp3

Tags: java, mp3, android-textview, android-mediaplayer, utf

Вот я например отображаю данные из `MediaStore.Audio.Media.Titel` столбца, какой то конкретной строчки, то есть обычный`.query()` запрос.
А эта строчка, которую мне возвращают из MediaStore, ее же непонятно кто и непонятно в каком подполье и даже непонятно в каком веке писал, то есть довольно часто в конечный view отрисовываются инопланетные символов, хотя в обычном плеере те же подразумеваемые поля отображаются корректно.
Так вот, куда мне копать хотя бы, подскажите. Как расшифровать эти крокозябры

Comment: проблема с русскими символами?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да